# Remove all packages in a text file via apt-get

Tags: shell-script, apt

I have a text file with a package on each line.  How can I remove all of the packages in that text file from the system?

Also, if one package cannot be removed/wasn't installed in the first place, I need the operation to continue.

I would ideally like a `sudo apt-get remove packages.txt` style solution.

Comment: Others answered you, But careful in using `apt-get`  or so on for removing. I prefer to use `dpkg --purge MYPACKAGE ` , because remove just remove and `--purge` remove files and control files.Second note is dependecies , did you check them?

Comment: @seg_fault The ability to delete configuration files with package removal (which is what `--purge` does) isn't specific to `dpkg`. You can also use `sudo apt-get purge packagename` or (equivalently) `sudo apt-get --purge remove packagename`. Furthermore, you will often *not* want to remove configuration files, as they take up very little space and you might want to reinstall the package (and have it use the previous configuration) in the future.

Comment: I'm sure that dpkg has --purge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get remove `cat packages.txt`
```

This should ignore packages that you don't have installed. I'm not sure what would happen if a package "cannot be removed" (since I've never seen this happen before).

Be sure to inspect the "`The following packages will be REMOVED:`" list to ensure nothing unexpected is removed.

Comment: +1, but backticks are evil :). use `$(cat packages.txt)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

If the package list is added in FILE1 and you want to remove all of them then:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in \`cat $1`
do
       dpkg -${2} $i
done
```

Now save this file as script.sh and execute it with two parameter
i. Name of the file in question
ii. "r" for removal and "i" for installation

Comment: For every single package, mentioned per line in file, will be deleted. What else you are seeking for ?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: this will be horribly slow, as it will run dpkg for each package/file individually.  Also the 'i' install option will only work on filenames, not package names...and even if you have all the files already downloaded and ready to install, the install may fail due to unsatisfied dependencies.  Similarly, the 'r' remove option may fail if you try to remove a package which another installed package depends upon.  lk-'s `apt-get` solution is much better.